# How do I customize WCF's "service not found" error?

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I have some spare time on the project I'm working on and want to customize the WCF "Service not found" error with something useful, humorous, or matches the site's 404 page.

How can I customize the WCF "service not found" error?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the bellow code under system.web node in your config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```